# pie doesn't allow negative values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am trying to draw a pie chart using Matplotlib, though there are no negative values present, I keep getting the error "pie doesn't allow negative values"!

```
contrib = sales_data.groupby('Region')['Sales2016'].sum().round().reset_index()
contrib["Percentage"] = (contrib.Sales2016/sum(contrib.Sales2016))*100
contrib = contrib.drop(columns = ["Sales2016"])
contrib.plot(kind = "pie", subplots = True).plot(kind = "pie",subplots=True,legend=False,figsize=(12,5),autopct="%.2f%%")
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to point out where am I going wrong? The following is the output for contrib:

```
Region  Percentage
0   Central 32.994771
1   East    42.701319
2   West    24.303911
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define argument `y` in the pie plot:

```
 contrib.plot(kind = "pie",y="Percentage",labels=['Region'],legend=False,figsize=(12,5),autopct="%.2f%%")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Gio, it is embarrassing that I missed out on it! Have a great day ahead.